# Can't set element in list to true

Tags: c#, list, boolean

```
 List<bool> Seeded = new List<bool>();

        // puts winning percentage into a list
        for (int i = 0; i < team.Count(); i++)
        {
            winPCTseed.Add(team.ElementAt(i).winPCT);
            Seeded.Add(false);
        }
```

That is how I filled a list full of boolean variables. I'm trying to set them to true but get an error saying left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer. I thought this code was.

```
Seeded.ElementAt(i) = true;
```

How can I set each element to true, after they've been set to false?

Comment: You can use `Seeded[i] = true`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. What are you actually trying to generate here? There's almost certainly a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your seeded list is empty and you don't have a condition to check whether winPCT is true or false when you adding them to winPCTseed and Seeded list.

```
    List<bool> Seeded = new List<bool>();

    // puts winning percentage into a list
    for (int i = 0; i < team.Count(); i++)
    {
        winPCTseed.Add(team.ElementAt(i).winPCT);
        Seeded.Add(true);
    }
```

But if you have a condition to check use as below.

```
    List<bool> Seeded = new List<bool>();

    // puts winning percentage into a list
    for (int i = 0; i < team.Count(); i++)
    {
        Seeded.Add(false);
        if(team[i].winPCT)
        {
          Seeded[i] = true;
          winPCTseed.Add(team.ElementAt(i).winPCT);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ElementAt` is an extension-method that only *returns* the element at the specified position. You can´t do much with that instance, as it´s a value-type which will be copied. Thus the instance returned by `GetElement` is completely independent from that instance that lives in your list.

But even if your list was a list of reference-types (=classes) you can´t do that, because you can´t assign a value to the return-value of a method.

In your case it´s pretty simple:

```
Seeded[i] = true;
```